# Instagram scraping - Unable to get redirected by requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, instagram

What I'm trying to achieve is to **obtain** an Instagram **username from an user id**. I'm trying to do this **without** an **Instagram API**, since my app is not approved. As I found out it can be done, at least in a browser, by going to the follow page which redirects to an url containing the username.

Lets use an Instagram id *184846987* as an example

By going to the url https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/184846987/follow/
I will get redirected to the page https://www.instagram.com/tsrod_/ which contains the username and can be easily extracted. Note that the user need to be logged in, in order for this to work.

So I'm trying to achieve this using python's requests library. I think that I have all the cookies needed to be able to do this. Here is a snippet.

```
    response = request_session.get(follow_url, allow_redirects=True)
    print(response.url)
```

This, however, does not redirect me anywhere. The code outputs the same URL as requested. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
follow_url="what_ever_you_put"
cookie={"sessionid":"your_session_id"}
resp=requests.get(follow_url, cookies=cookie , allow_redirects = True)
print(resp.url)
```

that is it

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I do. The problem is, that I don't get redirected. So the result URL is same as the original one.

Comment: i guess that you have not tried my code cause it works perfectly on my end

Comment: what is request_session.get that you have in your code?

Comment: Hi @ahmedmohamed do you know if there is an IP restriction from IG? Cause your code works well for me until a certain amount of links, do you think I need to make a break or change IP? Cheers